# ¿Como mostrar en la plantilla una imagen de mi modelo?

Tags: django

Ese es el resultado del template:

```
{% for eventos in eventos %}
    <h2>{{ eventos.nombre }}</h2>
    <p>{{ eventos.imagen }}</p>
    <p><b>Descripción:</b> {{ eventos.descripcion }}</p>
    <p><b>Fecha:</b> {{ eventos.fecha }}</p>
    <p><b>Hora:</b> {{ eventos.hora }}</p>
    <p><b>Lugar:</b> {{ eventos.lugar }}</p>
    <p><b>Ciudad:</b> {{ eventos.ciudad }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Necesito que la imagen se muestre, estoy usando django 1.10

[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]

Comment: Debes cargarlo en una etiqueta de `<img>` y añadirle como `src` la ruta de tu imagen con `{{ evento.imagen.url }}`

Answer (score 0):

Si declaraste el campo en el modelo como ImageField, solo tienes que llamarlo en la plantilla de la siguiente manera :

```
{% for eventos in eventos %}
    <h2>{{ eventos.nombre }}</h2>
    <p><img src="{{ eventos.imagen }}"></p>
    <p><b>Descripción:</b> {{ eventos.descripcion }}</p>
    <p><b>Fecha:</b> {{ eventos.fecha }}</p>
    <p><b>Hora:</b> {{ eventos.hora }}</p>
    <p><b>Lugar:</b> {{ eventos.lugar }}</p>
    <p><b>Ciudad:</b> {{ eventos.ciudad }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```